# Update and Select in one Hibernate query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to execute one query in Hibernate which looks like

```
private void setFailedLogins(String user_id) throws Exception {

      this.openDBTransaction();
      Query query = session.createQuery(
           "UPDATE User SET loginDate= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, loginAttempts=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loginHistory WHERE user_id=:user_id AND response!=:response AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,valTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 30*24*60) WHERE user_id=:user_id"
                  );
          query.setParameter("user_id", user_id);
          query.setParameter("response", "OK");
          int result = query.executeUpdate();
      this.closeDBTransaction();
   }
```

`loginAttempts` count is correct but then UPDATE query is not updating `loginAttempts` with that value

Additional info regarding Hibernate blow

Hibernate properties

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>

            <!-- Show and print nice SQL on stdout -->
            <prop key="show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

hibernate.hib_domain_package=com.retro.app.domain
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
hibernate.connection.username = ******
hibernate.connection.password = ******
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=8
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=300
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=40
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=3000
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Side note: When I change query to something simple like:

```
"UPDATE User SET loginDate= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, loginAttempts=66 WHERE user_id='USER_3000'"
```

Update is not taking any action on a database.

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have a transaction open? If yes check that the Session.commit() is call. Otherwise verify how the AutoCommit property is set, hibernate default strategy is false if i'm not wrong.

Comment: @BaptisteBeauvais I'm not sure about it as I'm new to Hibernate. Thought it will be easy as it is using PDO in PHP

Comment: It's not really more complicate, can you provide your hibernate configuration and the full method where you call the Query please, to see if that's confirm what i think.

Comment: @BaptisteBeauvais OP updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Got it solved but have no clue what is different.

Solution below:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
private void setFailedCount(String user_id) throws Exception {

      Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
      String hqlUpdate = "UPDATE User SET loginDate= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, loginAttempts=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loginHistory WHERE user_id=:user_id AND response!=:response AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,valTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 30*24*60) WHERE user_id=:user_id";
      int updatedEntities = session.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
              .setParameter("user_id", user_id)
              .setParameter("response", "OK")
              .executeUpdate();
      tx.commit();
      session.close();

   }
```